# Is it possible to make an op amp integrator that integrates a DC input?

Tags: operational-amplifier, dc, integrator

If the integral of a DC input is a ramp, can you make an op-amp circuit that integrates a DC input into a ramp, and then displays the ramp on an oscilloscope?

Comment: With [this](http://www.linear.com/product/LTC6090) you can integrate longer!

Comment: The problem is that non-idealities such as input offset voltage will cause the op-amp to saturate (you don't know which, even among devices of the same model). The idea of a DC integrator works great in theory, but it won't work well in reality. Typically an integrator is implemented as a low-pass filter (add a resistor in parallel to the capacitor), but this doesn't work for a DC input.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the textbook integrator circuit will output a ramp if you feed it a DC voltage. The inverting integrator is easiest.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4NYp7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Of course you have to establish an initial condition (for example, by shorting the capacitor) before you want the ramp to start. At some point the integrator will hit a limit (usually when the output approaches a supply rail) and the integration will stop.

In the above circuit the voltage will (ideally) be 0V just after the switch opens and and will ramp upward at 1 volt per second.

The op-amp inverting input is at a virtual ground (so long as it is balanced) so there is 1V across R1, and 1uA flows. The input ideally acts as an open circuit, so there must be 1uA flowing through the capacitor and thus dv/dt is 1V/second. When the output hits the (positive in this case) rail or thereabouts, the output will stop changing so the inverting input will no longer be at 0V- it will charge exponentially towards -1.0V with a time constant of 1 second.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple integrator circuit that takes integral of the input signal, no matter the shape of the signal.

[image]

Let's see how it works. Applying KCL at inverting input of the op amp, you get:

$$\frac{dV_{out}}{dt} = -\frac{V_{in}}{RC}$$

Integrating from both sides with respect to the time, we get:

$$V_{out}(t)=\int_{0}^{t} -\frac{V_{in}}{RC} dt + k$$
where k is output voltage at time t=0.

> If we apply a constant, positive voltage to the input, the op-amp output will fall negative at a linear rate, in an attempt to produce the changing voltage across the capacitor necessary to maintain the current established by the voltage difference across the resistor. Conversely, a constant, negative voltage at the input results in a linear, rising (positive) voltage at the output. The output voltage rate-of-change will be proportional to the value of the input voltage.

The quote was from this [website](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/semiconductors/chpt-8/differentiator-integrator-circuits/).

Answer (score 0):

With [this](http://www.electronics-tutorial.net/analog-integrated-circuits/op-amp-integrator/non-inverting-integrator/index.html) you can make a non- inverting integrator. Use a FET switch to reset the charge. Make C as small as possible and R as large as possible until input offset current becomes significant . Thus use FET input Op Amps for very slow integrators with NPO ceramic or plastic caps.

If just a crude ramp or sawtooth generator use a comparator to discharge the cap to ground at some threshold with some hysteresis to give enough discharge time.